# Search button displaying wrong result django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am creating a simple blog app with the help of django.

This is my models:

```
class categories(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='GST')


class Blog(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    Blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Description = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True,config_name='special')
    Blog_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_image', null=True, blank=True)
    Category = models.ForeignKey(categories,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Categories', null=True, blank=True)
```

This is the views I created for search:

```
def search(request):
    template = 'blog/blog_list.html'

    query = request.GET.get('q')

    if query:
       result = Blog.objects.filter(Q(Blog_title__icontains=query) | Q(Description__icontains=query) | Q(Category__Title__icontains=query))
    else:
       result = Blog.objects.filter(User=self.request.user).order_by('id')

return render(request, template)
```

In my Template:

```
             <form method='GET' class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'blog:search' %}">
              <div class="box-body">
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Search</label>

              <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input  name="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>

                 <div class="box-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Go</button>

                 </div>



        </form>
```

I dont know what is going wrong in the code...When I search for some Blog_title or description it gives a blank page...

Can anybody help me to figure out what went wrong in the code..

Thank you...

Comment: You don't send anything to the context in your render call.

Comment: you are not passing  blogs objects as context

Comment: Can you plz tell me how to do it actually I am very much new to django...plz

Answer (score 0):

change this  `return render(request, template)` to 
`return render(request, template, context={'blogs':result})`
and loop over it on blog_listing page